# logback variable substitution: check system variables BEFORE proeprties file

Tags: java, logging, configuration, environment-variables, logback

I have a logback application that specifies the logging file like this:

```
<appender name="FILE_APPENDER" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${FULL_PATH_TO_LOGFILE}</file>
    ...
```

The application is *normally* executed like this:

```
/usr/bin/java \
     -DFULL_PATH_TO_LOGFILE=/var/log/myApp/component1.log \
     -cp myApplicationsFatJar.jar com.Component1

/usr/bin/java \
     -DFULL_PATH_TO_LOGFILE=/var/log/myApp/component2.log \
     -cp myApplicationsFatJar.jar com.Component2
```

As you can see, different calls to the same jar will produce different log files for different components contained within the same fat jar.

There are certain situations there the application will *not* be called this way and `FULL_PATH_TO_LOGFILE` will not be defined, so I'd like the path to come from a properties file (in this scenario, all components will log to the same file which is not ideal, but is OK for this scenario). The problem is that as I understand it, logback will look at the properties file *first*, before checking system variables. I'd like it to do this lookup in the reverse order. Is this possible with logback?